# null is not an object error in simple countdown script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've a very simple script that displays a countdown in a div, and at the end of the countdown it redirects the page to a URL. It's working fine, but giving a "null is not an object" error. Id' like to understand why this is, and what to do fix.

Any help appreciated.

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    
    var timeLeft = 20;
    var elem = document.getElementById("calculation-countdown");
    var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
    
    function countdown() {
        if (timeLeft == -1) {
            clearTimeout(timerId);
            redirect();
        } else {
            elem.innerHTML = timeLeft + "<br />seconds";
            timeLeft--;
        }
    }
    
    function redirect() {
    window.location.replace("https://www.redirect-url-here-.com");
    }
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculation-countdown"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing that error in the code snippet above.  Where are you observing it?

Comment: Use `console.log()` to debug `redirect()` in your environment. Do you have a `window` object?

Comment: Sorted! I'm being a total and utter numpty, and running the script on all pages, not just the page with the calculation-countdown div. Of course, on the page WITH the div there's no error, but without...error!

Sometimes things are too obvious!